# How to initiate serializeUser method when user data has changed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I use `passportjs` with `passport-local` strategy to authenticate users in my project. Official `serializeUser` `deserializeUser` approach is the following:

```
// serialize and deserialize
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function(err, user){
     done(err, user.toJSON());
 })
});
```

But due to performance reason I need to prevent query User.findById to my MongoDB database so I use the following approach:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.toJSON());
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user);
});
```

But now I came up with the following problem: what if user change their data like name, age etc. How how could I update these without logout?

Actually I need to execute `passport.serializeUser` manually some how?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database session store then you're still just retrieving the entire `user.toJSON()` from database upon every `deserializeUser` call, something you thought you were avoiding but actually are not.

If you're not using a database session store, then you may be storing it all in a cookie or something which seems highly unsafe, as user object may contain sensitive information like password-hash.

If you just want to store users in memory, you should do just that. Create a cache that holds user objects.

```
var Users = {};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    Users[user._id] = user; // store in cache
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    if(Users[id]) return done(null, Users[id]); // retrieve from cache
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        if(err) return done(err);
        Users[id] = user; // store in cache now if wasn't already found
        done(null, user);
    });
});
```